# exchange information between processes in c++ and ruby

Tags: c++, ruby, concurrency

I have two concurrent and infinitive looping processes in ruby (eventmachine) and c++. How can I set up exchange information between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a modern tool like WebSockets:

- in C++ with [WebSocket++](http://www.zaphoyd.com/websocketpp)
- in Ruby with [EM-WebSockets](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket)

Set up a server in one of the two process, and connect with the other one as a client. Both processes will then be able to send and receive text and binary data implementing a few simple callbacks. Also, you will be able to check on your processes using a browser, a very useful feature.

Comment: Oh ok! What do you think about protobuf and so on?

Comment: Protocol Buffers are a good way to define your messages. Beware they could be overkill if you have just a few structures to pass back and forth. JSON is a simple alternative that comes to mind.

Comment: should I use json for exchange messages between ruby & c++ through websockets?

Comment: JSON is easy in Ruby, and in C++ you can use something like [JsonCpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) with a STL-like syntax (pretty intuitive as well). If JSON can fit your requirements, why not :-)